# LatLng object showing null in Android, googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps

LatLng object showing null in Android, googlemaps.I am getting `locationUpdateLatLng` value as `null`

**My Utils class:**

```
public static LatLng getLatLng(){
   return latLng;
}
```

**MyActivity Class:**

```
LatLng locationUpdateLatLng;
locationUpdateLatLng = Utils.getLatLng();
```

When I am calling `locationUpdateLatLng = Utils.getLatLng()` this is giving me the value null.`NullpointerException`

Comment: what value you have assigned to latLng in MyUtils class?

Comment: @Naveen post you code to Understand every one.

Comment: post your code...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will not work until you implement other neccessasry part of the code. Take a look at this official doc, very useful one: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-place-tutorial